# laravel preg_replace bold string before string including symbols

Tags: preg-replace, dompdf

I have a data to display which have certain to make it bold.

The data such as below:

Y.B. DATO' SRI HASAN BIN
ARIFIN [ ROMPIN ] minta

I want the word before 'minta' change to bold. Just like below

**Y.B. DATO' SRI HASAN BIN
ARIFIN [ ROMPIN ]** minta

I have use

```
$arr = explode("minta", $str, 2);
$first = $arr[0];
$str =preg_replace("^".$first."^", '<b>$0</b>', $str);
```

But its not working. Please help me.

Comment: Are the square brackets `[  ]` part of the string, do you want them to be bolded? Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58869094/edit) and add exact string and expected result.

Comment: Toto, i have edit my question. Yup, [ ] is part of the string.

Comment: i got the solution. Case closed.

Comment: If you got the solution, please, show it in the answer part, it will be usefull for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

My answer might looks long. As long as it works, im ok.

```
$a = explode("[", $str, 2);
$b = $a[0];
$str =preg_replace('~'.$b.'~', '<b>$0</b>', $str);
$str = preg_replace('#\[{1}(.*?)\]{1}#', '<b>$0</b>',  $str);
```